# Использование своего класса

Tags: yii2

Использую `Yii2 advanced` мне нужно разгрузить немного код в Контролере.

Я хочу создать сторонний класс и использовать его. Сделал папку в `common` и в ней написал класс, указал `namespace`, и подключил его (`use`) в контролере. Но выдает ошибку - такой класс не существует!

Класс, просто для того чтоб разгрузить код в контролере, то есть, в нескольких контролерах делается некая работа (одинаковая), я хочу сделать класс, чтоб вызывать с него функции - это значительно уменьшит количество кода, и сделает его рациональнее!

В commom сделал директорию `classes`, а в ней класс `UploadWorker`.

В этом классе указываю:`namespace common/classes;`

А там где создаю этот класс: `use common/classes/UploadWorker`;

*Oшибка говорит, о несуществующем классе по этому пути!*

**Как правильно реализовать такую задачу ? 
Где создавать ? И как правильно подключить класс ?**

Comment: Если говорит о том, что класс не существует, значит класс не существует — проверьте пути ещё раз.

Comment: @RomanGrinyov, спасибо кэп

Answer (score 3):

> В commom сделал директорию classes

не в commo**m**, а в commo**n**.

А проблема в неверном разделителе namespace. Разделитель не '/', а '\'.

Т.е не

```
use common/classes/UploadWorker
```

а

```
use common\classes\UploadWorker
```

И для таких задач лучше юзать треиты. Советую познакомиться с ними.